# Kinect vs Creative Senz3D

Tags: kinect

What are the advantages of Creative Senz3d? And what are the disadvantages? Which one should i buy? Is it worthy to deal with Creative?

Answer (score 0):

The Senz3D works with the Portal game Sixense where as the Kinect does not (as far as we know). Also, the Senz3D should come with special software that give you control of your computer with gestures where as the Kinect you have to build that yourself or go through hoops trying to find and install drivers and that special software for it. The Kinect works with many games you would find on the Microsoft store (I don't know if the Senz3D would be compatible...probably not) and works on your Xbox. Other than those, it's mostly just a toy for hackers and developers to just play with.

In conclusions, they both are kind of worthless

Comment: hi jeff! welcome. your answer hold a lot of info but is a bit hard to read, please space it a little bit. also since you dont recommend any of the above could you put your recommendation?